# How to run a function after setupIntentConfirmation succeeds?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I can successfully create and confirm a `setupIntent`. After the user enters his credit card details and presses the "confirm" button, his payment method is successfully attached to their stripe customer account. However, when the `setupIntent` is confirmed, I'd like to run a function on my client to send the user to a different screen.

This is where I check the completion of the `setupIntentConfirmation`. The print statement shows in the console but for some reason, my function is not running.

```
func onCompletion(status: STPPaymentHandlerActionStatus, si: STPSetupIntent?, error: NSError?) {
    self.setupIntentStatus = status
    self.error = error
    
    if status == .succeeded {
        
        print("succeeded")
        
        setIsVerifiedToTrue()
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the function I am trying to run:

```
func setIsVerifiedToTrue() {
    let ref = FirebaseReferenceManager.root.collection(FirebaseKeys.CollectionPath.requirements).document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

    ref.updateData([FirebaseKeys.RequirementsFieldPath.verified : true]) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error updating document: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("isVerified set to true")
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Isn't that another asynch thing?

Comment: @ElTomato I've wrapped the function in a 'DispatchQueue.Main.Async' along with another print statement. The print statement shows in the console but the function still doesn't run.

Comment: @devOP1 please give us your `myFunction()`

Comment: "I've wrapped the function in a 'DispatchQueue.Main.Async' along with another print statement."  How would that help when you deal with an ansyncronous process?

Comment: @erictruong I've just added it.

Comment: @ElTomato any suggestions then?